# How to find the host name of lotus note for spring batch

Tags: lotus-notes, spring-batch

I am implementing email sendind concept using spring batch but in the configuration it is asking for host namr, but I am unable to get my lotus name host name, how can I get it. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your Lotus Notes client. Select **Preferences** from the **File** menu.
2. Select **Locations** in the pane on the left. A list box will come up with your current location setting preselected.  Click on the **Edit** button. A tabbed dialog box will come up. Click on the **Servers** tab. Write down the name that appears in the **Home server** field. (Note: Use a pen and paper. Don't alt-tab out of that dialog to an editor window to type that name. Doing that might freeze your Notes client!)
3. Now select **Notes Ports** in the pane on the left. Select **TCPIP** in the list box, and click the the **Trace** button. Enter the name that your wrote down in the **Destination** field. (It will probably actually appear in the drop-down list for the field, but if there's more than one there be sure to check them against what you wrote down.) Click the **Trace** button. (Yes, this is the second button in a row labeled Trace). Watch the output in the box labeled "Trace info". You should find your server's host name or IP address in that output. (If you don't something's wrong, and you need to contact your Notes/Domino administration team.)